# Add LinkedIn login to Weebly site

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Can anybody tell me if it's possible to add the LinkedIn login details to a website I've created using Weebly?  I have had a go at this following the LinkedIN API instructions to add code to the header (which I have been able to do) and to the body.  Weebly has an option to allow HTML to be embeded into a page so I tried this for the body code but it dodn't seem to work.  When I viewed the HTML for the page I can see that the code is added but it doesn't seem to be in a "Body" section - in fact there doesn't appear to be a "body" section.

Answer (score 0):

[Escalate Hosting](http://www.escalatehosting.com/special/645199) Has an In=depth tutorial for LinkedIN's Developer Tutorials like this

Comment: Not as far as I can see.